# ng-blur don't fire event on firefox with input number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, onblur

I am trying to use ng-blur with an html input (type=number) element on **firefox**.

The problem I found is that when using the up and down arrows of the input number neither the blur nor the focus events are fired with firefox whereas with chrome works fine.

You can reproduce the issue in http://jsfiddle.net/chonw54e/

```
<div ng-app ng-init="focus=false;blur=false;active=false">
    <input type="number" ng-class="{ myFocus: focus, myBlur: blur }"    ng-focus="focus=true;blur=false;" ng-blur="blur=true;focus=false;">
    <p>focus: {{focus}}</p>
    <p>blur: {{blur}} </p>
</div>
```

Just load the page (with both firefox and chrome) and click on the up/down arrows of the html input number

[input number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frOzs.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** 11/12/2015

@Arg0n's solution fix the problem. However, it looks like a problem of either firefox or angularjs.

I have just created an issue on angular github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13508)

It is not an angular problem. It is due to the firefox's event behaviour which don't focus the input when clicking the arrows inside the input (which in my opinion is a mistake).

EDIT: 14/12/2015

Firefox Issue created in bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1232233

Comment: Ah, now i see what you mean. When you click on the arrows...

Comment: Yes, it works when you click on the "white space of the input" but fails with the arrows. Thanks for answering!

Comment: I had the same problem, i used ngModelChange instead of Blur Event, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this with jQuery, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/oLwfyao6/2/) fiddle:

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='number']").on("click", function(){
    $(this).focus();
  });
});
```

Without jQuery, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oLwfyao6/6/):

JavaScript

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].onclick = function() {
        this.focus();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will force the browser to focus on the `input` when it's clicked. (`Input` with `type` set to `number`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works fine but I amb only using AngularJS (it's a requirement of the project). I would like to know if it's a problem with angular or with the browser. I can't find the problem... Thanks again!!

Comment: Can you explain your solution?

Comment: Arg0n thanks for your help. I forked the first  jsfiddle with your proposal and it works. You can check the new code here http://jsfiddle.net/4ksywa6d/1/

Comment: @R3tep what Arg0n's solution does is find all the inputs with the type number and set the focus for each one. This way when the focus is lost (click outside the input) the blur is fired. Am I right, @Arg0n?

Comment: @CarlosVicient Not exacly, it finds all inputs with type number (So far you are correct), but it does not set focus. It binds an `onclick` event that, when you click anywhere inside the input (including the arrows), the input gets focus.

Comment: I see @Arg0n. Thanks again

Comment: @CarlosVicient No problem, please mark as answer if this helped you.

Comment: @Arg0n Your jQuery code works in Mobile FireFox in 2019. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A simple `onclick="this.focus();"` will work as nicely and much simpler if you have one field or using Angularjs's `ng-repeat`.